# Issue in iterating data and putting in csv file in php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I made this code

```
 private function FileLog($parsedData)
{

        $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/logs/'.date('d-m-Y').'.csv','a+');
        $HeaderKey = array();
        foreach($parsedData as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $key."<br>";//$key has names of all parameters
            foreach($value as $key1 => $value1)
            {
                echo $key1." :: ".$value1."<br>";//value1 has all the values
            }
            $HeaderKey[] = $key;
        }
        fputcsv($fp,$HeaderKey);
        fclose($fp);
}
```

This is what the output is

```
StartTag
0 :: $$
1 :: $$
2 :: $$
3 :: $$
LastUpdateTimeInSec
0 :: 1539544229
1 :: 1539544293
2 :: 1539544505
3 :: 1539544548
NumberOfParams
0 :: 22
1 :: 22
2 :: 22
3 :: 22
```

As you can see **$key1 give keys and $value1 give values**...What i want to do  is to put all the values with same keys together. 0 **startTag** value with 0 **LastUpdateTimeInSec** and with 0 **NumberOfParams** together and so on with 1,2 and 3. And finally put in csv file in that sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_map to combine data to output array

```
private function FileLog($parsedData)
{
    $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/logs/'.date('d-m-Y').'.csv','a+');
    $output = array_map(null, $parsedData['StartTag'], $parsedData['LastUpdateTimeInSec'], $parsedData['NumberOfParams']);
    foreach($output as $line) {
       fputcsv($fp, $line);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: splash58 it woked but it gives to notices that Notice: Undefined index: StartTag, than a warning that Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array and  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...why is that and can you also please explain $ouput.

Comment: it means that index StartTag is not present in your array. I have written it because it was in the question. Print your input array and look.